# NEW POP UP WINDOW resizing is not resizing when we click link in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

```
onclick="return PopupDocument(this.href,'myPop1',630,420)"
```

In IE11 a new window is not resizing when we click on link, where in google chrome I am able to resize new window

Answer (score 0):

You can open a resizable popup by using the [`resizable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) of `window.open`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a.popup_link').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    window.open(this.href, 'myPop1', 'width=630,height=420,resizable=yes');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<a class="popup_link" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: but it is not working in Internet Explorer 11 browser can please look at it. this is challenging part here.

Comment: I tested it in IE 11, and it works for me. Try opening your developer console (F12 and « Console » tab), and see if there are any errors in there when you try to open the popup